# Using ReaderT transformer in ScottyT (vs ActionT)

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, scotty

I'm trying to thread configuration through my Scotty based application using ReaderT monad transformer approach, and having trouble doing so. I have to use configuration both when defining routes (as some of them depend on the config) and when handling actual requests.

The latter works just fine in the ActionT, but no matter what I try I just can't get the types right in ScottyT.

Here's the minimal example I compiled from the ReaderT sample from Scotty GitHub repository:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Reader (MonadIO, MonadReader, ReaderT, asks, lift, runReaderT)
import Data.Default.Class (def)
import Data.Text.Lazy (Text, pack)
import Prelude
import Web.Scotty.Trans (ScottyT, get, scottyOptsT, text, capture)

data Config = Config
  { environment :: String
  } deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

newtype ConfigM a = ConfigM
  { runConfigM :: ReaderT Config IO a
  } deriving (Applicative, Functor, Monad, MonadIO, MonadReader Config)

application :: ScottyT Text ConfigM ()
application = do
  get "/" $ do
    e <- lift $ asks environment
    text $ pack $ show e

  path <- lift $ asks environment
  get (capture path) $ do
    text $ pack $ "Hello, custom path"

main :: IO ()
main = scottyOptsT def runIO application where
  runIO :: ConfigM a -> IO a
  runIO m = runReaderT (runConfigM m) config

  config :: Config
  config = Config
    { environment = "Development"
    }
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
• No instance for (Control.Monad.Trans.Class.MonadTrans
                     (ScottyT Text))
    arising from a use of ‘lift’
• In a stmt of a 'do' block: path <- lift $ asks environment
```

I've looked through the code where ScottyT type is outlined, and indeed there doesn't seem to be an instance of MonadTrans defined for it.

However, I don't feel I have enough both mana and Haskell experience to find a way out of it and would appreciate any help!

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I believe the ScottyT monad is intentionally barebones to hold only routing information. Note that you can simply pass your config to the `application` call: `main = scottyOptsT def runIO $ application config where`

Comment: If you want to use the config to define routes, you probably want `ReaderT Config (ScottyT Text IO)` instead of your current type. This is a trivial use of Reader anyways (i.e. no `local`); if that's really the case, you may as well use the type `Config -> ScottyT Text IO ()`

Comment: Passing config in a parameter is a viable alternative too, but that's exactly the reason I've initially started to factor out a `Reader`. I had this `Config` passed all over the place, and it looked like a perfect `Reader` use case. Having it passed in a parameter in one place and being wrapped within a monad in another doesn't seem as clean.

Comment: Just to clarify myself, I need config both to define routes and later on when serving requests.

Comment: Inspecting the `ScottyT` definition shows that it's definitely not a transformer. It's just a state monad. The `m` parameter is about the middleware and the error handlers you can put in the state. So if it's ok for you to have the config only there, then you can use `ScottyT` with `ReaderT`. Otherwise, you'll need something else.

Comment: That's what I figured, @Turion. Thanks. There also was a change around 2015 that dispensed `ScottyT` with being a monad transformer. Hence I'm left with either trying to use the older version or just wrapping `ScottyT` in my transformer. Ended up with the second option and type of `ConfigM (ST.ScottyT Text ConfigM ())`. Not particularly beautiful, but still ended up being cleaner than passing the parameters around.

Comment: Very good :) (if you want, you can post this as an answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a collective mind we all came to a currently viable solution to the problem.

ScottyT type cased to be a monad transformer with after https://github.com/scotty-web/scotty/pull/167 got merged, therefore there's currently no way of using it this way. There was a PR https://github.com/scotty-web/scotty/pull/181 aimed at bringing that feature back, but as far as I understood it has never got merged.

Since it's not a monad transformer we can only wrap it again:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Reader (MonadIO, MonadReader, ReaderT, asks, lift, runReaderT)
import Data.Default.Class (def)
import Data.Text.Lazy (Text, pack)
import Prelude
import Web.Scotty.Trans (ScottyT, get, scottyOptsT, text, capture)

data Config = Config
  { environment :: String
  } deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

newtype ConfigM a = ConfigM
  { runConfigM :: ReaderT Config IO a
  } deriving (Applicative, Functor, Monad, MonadIO, MonadReader Config)

application :: ConfigM (ScottyT Text ConfigM ())
application = do
  path <- asks environment

  return $
    get "/" $ do
      e <- lift $ asks environment
      text $ pack $ show e

    get (capture path) $          
      text $ pack $ "Hello, custom path"

runIO :: Config -> ConfigM a -> IO a
runIO c m = runReaderT (runConfigM m) c

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let config = Config { environment = "/path" }
  app <- runIO config application
  scottyOptsT def (runIO config) app
```

Thanks everyone for helping me out, and hopefully this helps another wandering Scotty like me :).