# Avoiding Orphan Instances with Monad Transformers

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I have monad transformers corresponding to independent features of my app.

In **Weather module**:

```hs
class Monad m => WeatherT m where
  byCity :: String -> m WeatherData

newtype MockWeather m a = MockWeather { 
  ... 
} deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadTrans)


instance Monad m => WeatherT (MockWeather m) where
  ...
```

In **Counter module**:

```hs
class Monad m => CounterT m where
  increment :: m Int
  current :: m Int

newtype MockCounter m a = MockCounter {
  ...
} deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadTrans)

instance Monad m => CounterT (MockCounter m) where
  ...
```

They both may have multiple instances with different implementations, for example they both have a mock instance that I use here in my main: `MockCounter` and `MockWeather`.

In the **Main module** I define `MyApp` monad as:

```hs
newtype MyAppM m a = MyAppM { unMyAppM :: MockCounter (MockWeather m) a }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, CounterT, WeatherT)
```

This definition requires me to make `(MockCounter (MockWeather m)` an instance of `WeatherT`:

```hs
instance Monad m => WeatherT (MockCounter (MockWeather m))
```

I define this instance in the main module, because I don't want Weather and Counter modules to depend on each others.

But defining this instance in the main module makes it an Orphan instance.

Questions:

- Am I on the right track here with `CounterT`, `WeatherT` and `MyAppM`? I want to build my app by composing decoupled and mockable functionalities.
- How can I avoid orphan instances?

[Full code](https://glot.io/snippets/eyxv46rb9l):

**Main module**

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module Main where

import          Counter
import          Weather

newtype MyAppM m a = MyAppM { unMyAppM :: MockCounter (MockWeather m) a }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, CounterT, WeatherT)

instance Monad m => WeatherT (MockCounter (MockWeather m))

runMyAppM :: Int -> MyAppM m a -> m (a, Int)
runMyAppM i = runMockWeather . (`runMockCounter` i) . unMyAppM

myApp :: (Monad m, CounterT m , WeatherT m) => m String
myApp = do
  _ <- increment
  (WeatherData weather) <- byCity "Amsterdam"
  return weather

-- Testing it:
main :: IO ()
main = runMyAppM 12 myApp >>= print
```

---

**Weather module**:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module Weather where

import           Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import           Control.Monad.Trans.Identity

newtype WeatherData = WeatherData String deriving (Show)

class Monad m => WeatherT m where
  byCity :: String -> m WeatherData

  default byCity :: (MonadTrans t, WeatherT m', m ~ t m') => String -> m WeatherData
  byCity = lift . byCity


newtype MockWeather m a = MockWeather {
  unMockWeather :: IdentityT m a
} deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadTrans)

runMockWeather :: MockWeather f a -> f a
runMockWeather = runIdentityT . unMockWeather

instance Monad m => WeatherT (MockWeather m) where
   byCity city = MockWeather $ return $ WeatherData $ "It is sunny in " ++ city
```

---

**Counter module**:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module Counter where

import           Control.Monad.Identity
import           Control.Monad.State
import           Control.Monad.Trans.Class

class Monad m => CounterT m where
  increment :: m Int
  current :: m Int

  default increment :: (MonadTrans t, CounterT m', m ~ t m') => m Int
  increment = lift increment

  default current :: (MonadTrans t, CounterT m', m ~ t m') => m Int
  current = lift current


newtype MockCounter m a = MockCounter {
  unMockCounter :: StateT Int m a
} deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadTrans, MonadState Int)

defaultMockCounter :: MockCounter Identity ()
defaultMockCounter = MockCounter $ put 0

runMockCounter :: MockCounter m a -> Int -> m (a, Int)
runMockCounter = runStateT . unMockCounter

instance Monad m => CounterT (MockCounter m) where
  increment = MockCounter $ do
    c <- get
    let n = c + 1
    put n
    return n

  current = MockCounter get
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an instance `WeatherT m => WeatherT (MockCounter m)` which just lifts a `WeatherT m` instance through `MockCounter m` thanks to the fact that `MockCounter` is a monad transformer. (The point of the default methods you wrote is to define such instances.)

To avoid orphan instances, one way is to separate `Weather` and `Counter` each into `Class` and `Trans` modules. `Class` don't need to depend on each other, while each `Trans` module may depend on all the `Class` modules (the other way around is also possible, and is in fact how `mtl` does it, but IMO `Trans` depending on `Class` is better: `Class` defines the interface, and `Trans` the implementation).

This is indeed a (known) problem because if you have `n` transformers and `m` classes, you potentially need `n*m` lifting instances. One solution is to define a polymorphic overlappable instance for all transformers `(MonadTrans t, WeatherT m) => WeatherT (t m)`. Overlapping instances are often frowned upon but I'm not sure what actual problems there are in this case.

By the way, following the naming convention from `mtl` and `transformers` we would have `MonadWeather` and `MonadCounter` classes, and `WeatherT` and `CounterT` types (monad Transformers).

Comment: Overlapping instances are my least-favorite language extension. I will admit that their problems *probably* won't bite in the context of test mockups. One problem is that it's especially easy to forget to override a default in an instance if you never write the instance; this can lead to people using nonsense instances by mistake. There can also be complications with existentials, and using things like Data.Constraint.Forall.